# How to avoid downloading all transitive dependencies of a maven dependency which already is a jar with all of its dependencies?

Tags: java, maven

I have two maven projects:

- Project A has many dependencies in its pom.xml but generates a jar with all of its dependencies which can be used as dependency itself using a classifier in the pom:

```
<profile>
            <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

- Project B uses project A as dependency but uses the jar with dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
</dependency>
```

My problem: I have a clean workspace checkout project B and freshly build it with:

```
mvn clean compile -U
```

Although it uses project A with dependencies, it downloads ALL transitive dependency jars from the pom.xml of project A which takes a long time. My goal was to use the jar with dependencies to make this go much faster. How can I prevent downloading everything from the pom.xml of project A when building project B?

My only idea would be to exclude all the transitive dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is this the official/only way to do this?

Comment: The problem with a jar-with-dependencies that it does not allow to use exclusion or overwrites etc. That's the biggest issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "official" way is to NOT use a `jar-with-dependencies` as dependency.

The concept of a `jar-with-dependencies` is meant to executable JARs.

For dependencies, it very rarely makes sense. On the other hand, it causes a lot of problems, if someone uses your project B as dependency and pulls the `jar-with-dependencies` transitively.

Comment: I see, it makes sense but what if I know that nobody will ever use my project B?

Comment: You should note that the download of transitive dependencies only happens once. After that, they are in your local repository.

Comment: I know but for my build it is always cleared before in Jenkins, so the download took longer than downloading the JAR with all dependencies. This is the reason I needed the JAR with dependencies to make the jenkins build faster and caching the workspace is currently no option. I think it works with excluding the dependencies in the pom.xml. However, it might be bad practice for many other usecases.

Comment: What is the problem with caching the local repository in Jenkins?